# multiple values from grafana variable in prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

We have a situation where we need to select the multiple values (instances/servers) from grafana variable field, and multiple values needs to passed to the Prometheus query using some regex, so that i can see selected hosts metrics in single graph. but i am not able to make it work. Can someone please help me with this.

lets take an example , if i select multiples values host1,host2,host3 and then the query should be looks something like this node_load1(instance="host1", instance="host2" , instance="host3").

Hope i made it clear my question.

Thanks in well advance.

Answer (score 28):

Grafana generates a regex for you when you [use the variable in queries](https://grafana.com/docs/features/datasources/prometheus/#using-variables-in-queries).

I assume you have a variable `$host` defined by collecting the label values.
Ex:

```
label_values(node_load1, instance)
```

Then simply use the request:

```
node_load1{instance=~"$host"}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer, it is working. I think when i was trying i missed "~" part , my bad.

Comment: or i might have looking with some other job name. I completely missed something when i was testing or before asking here :(

Answer (score 20):

Note that `node_load1{instance="host1",instance="host2",instance="host3"}` won't return any results, since the label filters are applied with `and` operation, e.g. the query means:

> select time series with `node_load1` name **and** with `instance="host1"` label **and** with `instance="host2"` label **and** with `instance="host2"` label

You need to use `or` operation for multiple `instance` label values. This can be done with the following query, which uses [regexp filter](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) for `instance` label:

```
node_load1{instance=~"host1|host2|host3"}
```

See [PromQL tutorial](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) for more details.

Grafana automatically constructs the `value1|...|valueN` regexp for `$var_name` template when multiple label values are selected for this variable. So just use `node_load1{instance=~"$host"}` in queries in Grafana as suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59165219/274937